# getTextContent on xml node returning null pointer exception

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, nullpointerexception

I am attempting to get the text from an xml node.  The code seems to recognize the node.  This code
    String L = "Node Length: " + nList.getLength()+ "  Text: " + nList.item(0).toString();
    jTextArea1.setText(L);

returns: `Node Length: 1  Text: [CompanyName: null]`

So it seems like the code is finding the node but not getting the value.  Here is the whole code block (this is my first time posting so I hope I formatted this right!).  the FOR loop should grab the value but is throwing a NULL Pointer Exception:

```
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
            try{
        //Get Document Builder
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        //Build Document
        Document xdocument = builder.parse(new File("request.xml"));
        xdocument.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = xdocument.getElementsByTagName("CompanyName");
        //String L = "Node Length: " + nList.getLength()+ "  Text: " + nList.item(0).toString();
                    //jTextArea1.setText(L);
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)
        {
            Node node = nList.item(0);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            {
                Element eElement = (Element) node;
                String nodetxt= "Company : "  + eElement.getElementsByTagName("CompanyName").item(0).getTextContent() ;
                jTextArea1.setText(nodetxt) ;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
          java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TechKnowPOSGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

and here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunReportQueryAction xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<CompanyName>Techknow</CompanyName>
<IntegrationLoginId>cwapitest</IntegrationLoginId>
<IntegrationPassword>cwtest123</IntegrationPassword>

<ReportName>Company</ReportName>
<!-- <Conditions></Conditions> -->
<!-- <Limit>10</Limit> -->
<!-- <Skip></Skip> -->
<!-- <OrderBy></OrderBy> -->

</RunReportQueryAction>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On  this line you get all the `CompanyName` elements:

```
NodeList nList = xdocument.getElementsByTagName("CompanyName");
```

Then you loop through them in your for loop and call this:

```
eElement.getElementsByTagName("CompanyName")
```

But that would imply that the `CompanyName` has nested `CompanyName` elements, which it does not. Therefore you should use this in your for loop, as the elements you are iterating are already the `CompanyName` elements:

```
String nodeTxt = "Company : " + eElement.getTextContent()
```

Comment: That works perfectly!  Thank you for the patient answer.  It was "googled" code and you've helped me understand it better.